# Simulate atomic redis incr command using transaction

Tags: redis, concurrency, python-asyncio

Considering example mentioned [here](https://redis.io/docs/manual/transactions/), it seems it is possible to create a lock using *WATCH* & *MULTI* commands to simulate *INCR* atomic command. The problem is GET and MULTI are not being executed atomically which causes **concurrent** hits not be correctly serialized and results invalid final value.

```
WATCH mykey
val = GET mykey
val = val + 1
MULTI
SET mykey $val
EXEC
```

A simple code using Python asyncio to concurrently hit redis incrementing a key, once with atomic INCR, and once using above approach. (python3.8, asyncio-redis==0.16.0)

```
import asyncio
import asyncio_redis

async def worker(_id):
    global cache_pool
    r = await cache_pool.incr('some_key')
    print(f"worker_id: {_id} - {r}")

async def connect():
    global cache_pool
    cache_pool = await asyncio_redis.Pool.create(host='localhost', port=6379, poolsize=10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(connect())
    for i in range(10):
        loop.create_task(worker(i))
    loop.run_forever()
```

result would be 10.

```
import asyncio
import asyncio_redis

async def worker(_id):
    global cache_pool

    while True:
        try:
            await cache_pool.watch(['some_key'])

            value = await cache_pool.get('some_key')
            value = int(value or '0')
            value += 1

            tr = await cache_pool.multi()
            await tr.set('some_key', str(value))
            await tr.exec()
        except asyncio_redis.exceptions.TransactionError:
            pass
        else:
            print(f"worker: {_id} got optimistic lock - {value}")
            break

async def connect():
    global cache_pool
    cache_pool = await asyncio_redis.Pool.create(host='localhost', port=6379, poolsize=10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(connect())
    for i in range(10):
        loop.create_task(worker(i))
    loop.run_forever()
```

some workers entering transaction block serially and therefore overriding newly incremented value.

Answer (score 0):

Redis already includes an [`INCR` command](https://redis.io/commands/incr/) which is atomic and does what you are looking for: there is no need to use transactions.

`> INCR mykey`

Comment: A complete irrelevant answer. You did not event pay attention to title!

Comment: The answer may appear irrelevant to _you_, @aliebrahimi: not a big deal, to be honest.

Comment: I am struggling to understand why the OP wants to do this and not just use the `INCR` command for it.  @aliebrahimi - what goal are you trying to achieve here, better understanding of this might lead to other answers.

Comment: @SimonPrickett - I am trying to understand the example mentioned in Redis transaction official document that it is possible to achieve the same with transaction what INCR gives. Why not discussing how it can be done with transaction and not repeating that it is useless.